# Can the `restrict` keyword be used in the function definition only?

Tags: c, keyword

I am wondering if it is possible to include the `restrict` keyword only in the function definition and not in the function declaration like so:

```
void foo(char *bar);

void foo(char * restrict bar)
{
    // do something
}
```

Since `foo` only takes one argument, any pointer aliasing would have to take place inside `foo`. There would be no need for the person calling the function to know about the `restrict` modifier. Would it be fine to omit the keyword in only the function declaration, just like with `const`?

Comment: Note: Those declarations aren't for the person, they're for the compiler.

Comment: "There would be no need for the person calling the function to know about the restrict modifier" --> Not so.  Consider `int fred[42]; foo(fred)` and `foo()` messes with the global `fred[]`.   The call violates `restrict`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why would that be? I thought that would be fine as long as nothing like `char *p = bar` happens inside the function.

Comment: @tadman: `restrict` in a function definition is for the compiler, but `restrict` on an argument in a declaration is for the programmer, it is ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 9):

You may use `restrict` on parameters in function declarations whether they are definitions or not, as it is allowed by the C grammar and there is no rule against it. However, they have no effect to the compiler in declarations that are not definitions. This is because 6.5.2.2 7 says qualifiers are removed when passing arguments to functions with prototypes:

> … the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

Thus, if a function declaration has a parameter of type `int * restrict a`, whatever argument you pass is converted to the unqualified type, `int *`.

Further, two otherwise identical function declarations are compatible even if the qualifiers on parameters are changed, because C 2018 6.7.6.3 15 says:

> … (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, … each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

However, this applies only to the parameter itself. The parameter is not affected by a `restrict` that qualifies it. But it can point to a pointer that is restrict-qualified. For example, `void foo(void * restrict *a);` and `void foo(void **a);` declare different function types.

Although qualifiers on parameters in declarations have no effect to the compiler, they can signal to humans that the arguments are expected to conform to the restriction. Inside the function definition, the parameter is restrict-qualified, and anybody calling the function should respect that.

Comment: I suppose having it in the declaration could also help the compiler provide better warnings or optimizations.

Comment: "6.5.2.2 7 says qualifiers are removed" It's important to note that this is qualifiers used by the passed type itself, not qualifiers by the pointed-at type. The "as if by assignment" part means that we can't pass a `const int*` to a function expecting an `int*`, but we can pass a `int* const`, because that's how the rules of assignment are stated.

Comment: In the end, the relevant part from the standard to quote is the rule about lvalue conversion 6.3.2.1/2 "...an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called _lvalue conversion_. If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue;"

Comment: @Lundin: The answer does state the qualifiers are removed from the parameter type and does state that pointed-to pointers can be restrict-qualified.

Comment: @Lundin: 6.3.2.1 2 is irrelevant because the argument type is dictated by 6.5.2.2 7. Whether 6.3.2.1 2 says qualifiers are removed or not during lvalue conversion, the arguments are converted to parameter types according to 6.5.2.2 7, which says they are converted to unqualified types. Conversely, if 6.5.2.2 7 said they were converted to the parameter types with their qualifiers, they would be converted to their parameter types with their qualifiers, regardless of what lvalue conversion had done. 6.3.2.1 2 has no effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

The next C99 source code can show you that the output of the program **depends** on restrict :

```
__attribute__((noinline))
int process(const int * restrict const a, int * const b) {
    *b /= (*a + 1) ;
    return *a + *b ;
}

int main(void) {
    int data[2] = {1, 2};
    return process(&data[0], &data[0]);
}
```

The software terminates with code 1 using **restrict** and 0 without **restrict** qualifier.
The compilation is done with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -O3 main.c`.
The flag `-O1` do the job too.

And so on.